# Error: "This operation can not be performed at runtime" when adding workflow activity at runtime

Tags: workflow, workflow-activity

I am adding SharePoint workflow activity at runtime, depends on configuration done by user in Workflow Association form.
I am adding simple log to history activity but getting error "This Operation can not be performed at runtime."
What can be issue, how to resolve this issue? Any idea?
[image]

Comment: No one here? at least some idea whether it is possible or not ?

Comment: Maybe this is not possible at runtime? Like the exception says?

Comment: @Gwny but there should be something, which I might missing. Otherwise there were no option for adding activities itself in Visual studio !

Comment: is this inside workflowchanges class?

Comment: No, its on WorkflowActivated invoke method